# data.sql is not invoked on startup

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I have following application.yml:

```
spring:
  profiles: test
  jpa:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
      generate-ddl: true
      ddl-auto: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test_db;MODE=MSSQLServer
    username: sa
    password:
    data: data.sql
    continue-on-error: true
flyway:
  enabled: false
```

and following project structure:

[image]

But data.sql is not invoked on startup

Comment: Do you see any warning about data.sql not being found? Have you tried to remove the data: data.sql line from your configuration? It is the default anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have to defer running data.sql until hibernate creates table. Add this to your application.yml:

```
jpa: defer-datasource-initialization: true
```